# Error: missing ; before statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, liferay-6

I am applying a javascript, but it fires the error:

```
**missing ; before statement**

String str = document.location.href;
alert(str);
str.replace( "/blogs/-/blogs", "blogs" );
```

Your any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: this is javascript.everything is var.

Comment: don't confuse Javascript with Java :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
String str = document.location.href;
```

to

```
var str = document.location.href;
```

You don't declare variables with a type in JavaScript but with the `var` keyword.